# Cleanly converting an Objective-C Boolean to a Swift Bool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing? Right now I'm doing this like so:

```
let doesConformNumber: NSNumber = NSNumber(unsignedChar: UTTypeConformsTo(utiCF, typeCF))
if doesConformNumber.boolValue {
    return true
}
```

If I try to do a simple cast like so:

```
let testBool: Bool = UTTypeConformsTo(utiCF, typeCF)
```

I get the error *'Boolean' is not convertible to 'Bool'*

Anyone have a cleaner way of doing this conversion?

Comment: `let testBool = doesConformNumber.boolValue` not enough?

Comment: the checked answer is cleaner, which is all I wanted

Comment: Note that `UTTypeConformsTo` returns a CoreFoundation boolean, `Boolean`; an Objective-C boolean is a `BOOL`. The question is a good one, the summary is just a bit misleading. But probably in a good way for searches. :)

Comment: Please note that at some point in the years since this question was asked, Apple changed the way Swift exposes `UTTypeConformsTo` so that it returns a native Swift `Bool`. No conversion is necessary in modern Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UTTypeConformsTo()` returns a `Boolean`, which is a type alias for `Int8` and not directly
convertible to `Bool`. The simplest way would be

```
let testBool : Bool = UTTypeConformsTo(utiCF, typeCF) != 0
```

where the type annotation is actually not necessary:

```
let testBool = UTTypeConformsTo(utiCF, typeCF) != 0
```

Comment: what's the difference between Bool and Boolean?

Comment: @jawanam: `Boolean` is a "historic Mac type" and defined as `Int8`. `Bool` is the Swift boolean type. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304158/type-boolean-does-not-conform-to-protocol-booleantype.

Comment: So it should use Bool over Boolean whenever it's possible?