# Type 'Boolean' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, osx-yosemite

In attempting to create a Launch Helper as per the Apple docs (and [tutorial-ized](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/)), I seem to be hitting a hiccup caused by porting the Objective-C code into Swift... who's compiler couldn't be any more redundant in this case.

```
import ServiceManagement

let launchDaemon: CFStringRef = "com.example.ApplicationLauncher"

if SMLoginItemSetEnabled(launchDaemon, true) // Error appears here
{
    // ...
}
```

The error seems to consistently be:

`Type 'Boolean' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'`

I have tried casting to `Bool` in a number of locations, in case I'm simply dealing with a [redundant, archaic primitive](https://twitter.com/dridus/status/520405642881007616) (either brought in by Obj-C or Core Foundation), to no avail.

Just in case, I have tried casting the response:

`SMLoginItemSetEnabled(launchDaemon, true) as Bool`

which yields the error:

`'Boolean' is not convertible to 'Bool'`

...seriously?

Comment: dear Chris, can you add my skype: contact@giauhuynh.com & help me implement SMLoginItemSetEnabled. I'm online right now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Boolean` is a "historic Mac type" and declared as

```
typealias Boolean = UInt8
```

so this compiles:

```
if SMLoginItemSetEnabled(launchDaemon, Boolean(1)) != 0 { ... }
```

---

With the following extension methods for the `Boolean` type
(and I am not sure if this has been posted before, I cannot find it right now):

```
extension Boolean : BooleanLiteralConvertible {
    public init(booleanLiteral value: Bool) {
        self = value ? 1 : 0
    }
}
extension Boolean : BooleanType {
    public var boolValue : Bool {
        return self != 0
    }
}
```

you can just write

```
if SMLoginItemSetEnabled(launchDaemon, true) { ... }
```

- The `BooleanLiteralConvertible` extension allows the automatic conversion of
  the second argument `true` to `Boolean`.
- The `BooleanType` extension allows the automatic conversion of the `Boolean`
  return value of the function to `Bool` for the if-statement.

---

*Update:* As of **Swift 2 / Xcode 7 beta 5,** the "historic Mac type" `Boolean`
is mapped to Swift as `Bool`, which makes the above extension methods
obsolete.

Comment: Hey I liked `Boolean(1)` -- makes it more understandable what you're calling it with. :)

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this combination... It works, though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right, I had a similar issue trying to get the BOOL return of an objective-C method in Swift.

Obj-C:

```
- (BOOL)isLogging
{
    return isLogging;
}
```

Swift:

```
    if (self.isLogging().boolValue)
    {
        ...
    }
```

this was the way that I got rid of the error.