# What parameters shoud I pass to SMLoginItemSetEnabled?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

I try to make an app to run at login using a helper. now i have only one thinh to do : to set SMLoginItemSetEnabled.

in Objective c it was easy

```
 if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled((__bridge CFStringRef)@"Test.MyTestApp", (BOOL)[sender state])) {
     NSLog(@"The login was not successful");
}
```

but, in swift compiler complaine about : "Cannot invoke 'SMLoginItemSetEnabled' with an argument list of type '(CFString, Boolean)'"

```
   let str = "Test.MyTestApp"
    let cfStr:CFString = str as NSString
    let state:Boolean = 1

    if  SMLoginItemSetEnabled(cfStr  , state){
        println("The login was not successful")
    }
```

Have any idea what is corect way to call this function?

Comment: Please check this for help: [Type 'Boolean' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304158/type-boolean-does-not-conform-to-protocol-booleantype)

Comment: Thanks. Initialy i try with true , false, and after that i have seen that second parameter was a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using the following (in Swift 2.0)

```
let b = enabled ? 1 : 0
if SMLoginItemSetEnabled(bundleIdentifier as CFString, Boolean(b) as Boolean) == 0 {
    NSLog("Unable to update startup item to \(enabled) for \(bundleIdentifier)")
}
```

Comment: in the end i find the error in my code. The compiler complains about state var. I resolved this error with an extension for Boolean                                   extension Boolean : BooleanLiteralConvertible {
    public init(booleanLiteral value: Bool) {
        self = value ? 1 : 0
    }
}

Comment: Yes, I noticed something similar, but I was mostly stumped by the compiler complaining about the arguments to SMLoginItemSetEnabled(...) until I added the "== 0" check at the end of the if statement. Apple haven't made it easy for us with that one. :)