# Swift - Bool vs Boolean

Tags: swift, boolean

I am teaching myself to program using Swift 3, and I am currently learning about booleans. I noticed that if I want to explicitly declare my variable of type bool, I have two options

> Bool

or

> Boolean

I was wondering why we have these two options if they are the same? Well, are they the same? This is what I'm confused about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Swift native type is Bool

Comment: Where do you see `Boolean`? If I try to use that as a variable's type it shows an error.

Comment: @rmaddy the tutorials I was watching were a bit old and the guy said to just google it if we wanted to know the reasoning, in the current version of Xcode we can no longer do it, but I was just asking because I was curious.

Comment: `Boolean` used to be an alias for `UInt8` in Swift 1.x for "historic reasons", compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304158/type-boolean-does-not-conform-to-protocol-booleantype/27304432#27304432

Answer (score 5):

`Bool` is Swift's boolean data type. `Boolean` hasn't existed since the early days of Swift.