# How to convert Objective-C BOOL to Swift's Bool with NSError** as one of the parameter in return

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a project in which I am trying to use Swift for the new modules. For one of the new class, I am using an existing method of an Objective-C class in Swift 3.2.

Following is the signature of the method,

```
- (BOOL)canLoginWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error
```

I am trying to use this method in swift as,

```
    if try loginLogicHandler.canLogin(withUsername: usernameValue, password: passwordValue) as Bool {

}
```

However, I am getting a compiler error as

> Cannot convert value of type () to type 'Bool' in coercion

What should I do to make this working?

Could anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this link it might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561096/cleanly-converting-an-objective-c-boolean-to-a-swift-bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561096/cleanly-converting-an-objective-c-boolean-to-a-swift-bool)

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/45565960/2976878

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C methods that return `BOOL` and return an `NSError` by reference are exposed to Swift as methods that use the `try`/`catch` error-handling mechanism, and return `Void`. If you look at the generated interface, you'll probably see that it looks something like this:

```
func canLogin(withUsername: String, password: String) throws // notice no return type
```

If the Objective-C method fails, it returns `NO`, and populates the error pointer, and Swift then throws that error. So, you need to use `try` and `catch`:

```
do {
    try loginLogicHandler.canLogin(with: bla, and: bla)

    // if canLogin returned YES, you get here
} catch {
    // if canLogin returned NO, you get here
}
```

Alternately, you can use `try?`. This one's kind of weird; you'll get an optional `Void`, so you'll get `Void` if the method succeeds, or `nil` if it fails:

```
if (try? loginLogicHandler.canLogin(with: bla, and: bla)) != nil {
    // the method returned YES
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Charles!